# Erro conexão mysql com c. Unknown type name 'SOCKET'

Tags: mysql, c

Possuo este código e está gerando erro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sys\socket.h>

void main(void)
{

    //parâmetros para Conexão
    char host[100];
    char user[100];
    char pass[100];
    char db[100];
    char script[500];

    //variáveis para conexão e manipulação dos objetos do banco
    MYSQL *socket;
    MYSQL_RES *resp;
    MYSQL_FIELD *campos;
    MYSQL_ROW linhas;   
}
```

[image: Erro Gerado]

Mais informações:

Compilador: Orwell Dev-C++

Sistema Operacional: Windows 8 x64

MySQL x32

Comment: Tem que adicionar as lib pré-compiladas

Comment: @Tony eu fiz isso e não deu certo. Só pra conferir, é lá nos parâmetros do projeto, no campo linker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui encontrar o erro, é necessário dar o include do socks antes do mysql.
No meu caso ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
//#include <sys\socket.h>
```